# Shell extension windows : best communication between ContextMenu and IconOverlay?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shell-extensions

Hello windows experts,

I am searching for a simple way to activate an overlay on files using the context menu. Tortoise SVN gives an example of what can be done. But is very complex compared to my simple need.

For now I am looking at approaching it this way using C++:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/545781/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Icon-Overlay-Handlers

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer

The issue is to create the link between both of them. The following link suggests to make a map but I am quite puzzle about how:

[What the best Language to use when creating Windows Shell Context Menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980970/what-the-best-language-to-use-when-creating-windows-shell-context-menu)

Comment: The context menu and overlay do not communicate with each other. Instead, they communicate with a common back end that maintains the extension state for all files.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, that's precisely this back end that I am trying to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Registry, for example store an `Enabled` value in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\YourCompany\YourApp` key. When the user executes your menu item to turn on/off the functionality, write the appropriate value into `Enabled` and then call `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, nil, nil)`. That will cause the shell to re-read icons, including icons from your overlay extension. Inside the `IsMemberOf` method of your `IconOverlay` handler, check your `Enabled` value and return `S_FALSE` if the functionality has been turned off.

Comment: Thanks that's a very nice way to do it,
I'll test it right away

Comment: this is working
msdn reference is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
best thing to do is to notify the file system, this way explorer will be notified anyway